# Networking between flex environment app engine and cluster engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, networking, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I can ping a VM started with 'create cluster' command from the app engine VM. However the names given to the cluster VMs are not user friendly (such as gke-mongo-cluster-default-pool-37e9b787-k7wl). I would like to assign a cleaner name to the VM - such as mongo-1 . When I deploy with deployment manager (say mongodb); I do get such cleaner names.

So the question is,

(1) How can I assign names to the VMs created under a gcloud cluster created with create-cluster command?

(2) Is there another way to map a name to an IP address within the project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) How can I assign names to the VMs created under a gcloud cluster created with create-cluster command?

This isn't possible. The names are chosen for you by Google Container Engine and have names assigned such that the number of nodes in the cluster can be dynamically scaled up and down without creating naming conflicts.

It isn't clear why you are trying to ping a node directly. You can create a [Kubernetes service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) running inside your GKE cluster that has a stable name that you can address.

Comment: $ kubectl get services

mongo-1      10.63.242.52    XXXXX   27017/TCP   5d

mongo-2      10.63.244.227   XXXXX  27017/TCP   3d 

I am unable to ping to names mongo-1 and mongo-2 (or the internal IP addresses) from the app engine/flex environment (the last time I tried). I wanted to use names addresses ; as IP addresses can change if I stop and restart mongo servers. ~ TIA (please do correct me)

Comment: By default, the names and IP addresses of a kubernetes service will only be resolvable / reachable (respectively) from a node within the GKE cluster. You can make the IP addresses resolvable by creating GCE advanced routes for the IP addresses that point to a node in the cluster. And the IP addresses associated with services are stable (the addresses of the pods can change but the service remains static). Your other option is to *expose* the service which will create a stable *external* IP address. You can then use that address directly or create a manual DNS entry and use your DNS name.

Comment: Thanks. Though the IP addresses with services are stable but they don't persist between shutting down a VM and launching it again. I will try the other approaches - I particularly wanted to be able to use a name (its most user friendly). ((additionally, maybe you can undo the downvote - unless you think it still holds)) cheers

Comment: Service IPs (which are either virtual or externalized addresses) should be stable until you delete the service. They should not be tied to the lifetime of a single VM.